# copy item in specific location in list elements to new list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

Well-experienced in C++, but new-ish to Python:  I'd like to pull out the 2nd character in each element of the following list named input to a new list named output.

```
input = ['hail','2198','1721','1925']

output = ['a', '1', '7', '9']
```

Am I missing a simple operator that does this?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Welcome to programming in Python :) .

The syntax for getting a character out of the string `s` is `s[i]` where i starts with 0 and goes up to n-1 where n is the length of the string.

In Python it is possible to create a list of elements using a syntax that explains itself when reading it. `item[1]` means in this context the second character/element in the string got from input because Python considers in this context a string to be a list of characters.

The right keywords to search the Internet for details will be "Python list comprehension" and "Python list slice".

```
output = [item[1] for item in input_] (see note in the other answer about 'input')
```

Compared to C++ Python will make coding a pleasure. You have just to write what you mean it has to be that way and it probably will be that way in Python - that is how I came from C++ to Python myself.

Comment: super, easier but also a different metaphor--if you have thoughts on my comment below, thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's a list comprehension:

```
>>> input_ = ['hail','2198','1721','1925']
>>> [s[1] for s in input_]
['a', '1', '7', '9']
```

Note that `input` is the name of a built-in function in Python, so you should avoid to use that name for a local variable.

Comment: great, also, what if character after character '2'?   ['1', '1', '5']

Comment: @king2 i have proposed solution for the choosing character after`'2'`

Answer (score 1):

This is for the character after `'2'`.

```
input_ = ['hail','2198','1721','1925']
result_list = []
for element in input_:
    character = '2' # in this case
    index_of_character = element.find(character)
    if index_of_character != -1 and index_of_character != len(element) -1:
        # -1 if character is not found in the string no need to append element after that
        # character should not be the last in the string otherwise index out of bound will occur
        result_list.append(element[index_of_character + 1])

print (result_list)
```

PS: This method only gives character only after first occurrence of two if there are multiple `'2'` in the string. You have to tweak this method

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it in one line using list-comprehension. You can select the second index element using `input[i][1]` at some index i.

```
>>>input = ['hail','2198','1721','1925'] 
>>>[x[1] for x in input]
['a', '1', '7', '9']
```

`[x[1] for x in input]` will create a list of elements where each element will be `x[1]`.